# What is the difference between Unit.type and Unit

Tags: scala, types

I have the method below:

```
override def insertAll(notifications: Seq[PushNotificationEncoded])
                      (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] = {
  val f = Future.sequence(notifications.map(insert)).map(_ => Unit)
  f.onFailure { case ex => sys.error(s"Got exception whilst saving PushNotification: $ex") }
  f
}
```

It gives the following compiler error:

```
  type mismatch;
  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Unit.type]
  required: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]
     f
     ^
```

I thought Unit was a type with a single element, thus there shouldn't be any confusion when it comes to Unit. I tried googling this but I couldn't find any more information about what "Unit.type" is.

If I simplify the method like this, then it works fine:

```
override def insertAll(notifications: Seq[PushNotificationEncoded])
                      (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] =
  Future.sequence(notifications.map(insert)).map(_ => Unit)
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unit's sole instance is `()`.  `Unit` used as a value is the companion object for Unit (which mainly manages boxing and unboxing)

```
val f = Future.sequence(notifications.map(insert)).map(_ => ())
```

Answer (score 2):

`x.type` is the *singleton type* of `x`: the type whose only two values are `x` and `null`. `x` must be a "stable identifier" of a value, such as the companion object of `Unit`.

Answer (score -1):

Types in scala are objects too, and, as any object, have their own types. 
`()` is an instance of type `Unit`. `Unit` is an instance of `Unit.type`. 
(I don't think there is a way to go even higher - no such thing as `Unit.type.type` though).

For most non-esoteric purposes, you don't need to worry about it, just use `()` whenever you need to reference an instance of type `Unit`, you shouldn't really need the other one anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first paragraph is pretty completely incorrect: 1. Types aren't objects (they have objects which represent them in Scala reflection, but that's not relevant here); 2. Not all objects have their own types; 3. The `Unit` which is instance of `Unit.type` is not the type `Unit` but its companion object, as Ramsey's answer says (the relation between them is quite weak in Scala).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying